# How to implement the suspend keyword to modify higher-order functions in kotlin poet

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I want to modify higher-order functions with the ”suspend“ keyword. The following is what I want:

```
public fun login(io: suspend () -> ResLogin): Unit {}
```

I tried to use:

```
val lambdaTypeName = LambdaTypeName.get(returnType = responseBean)
```

But get the following code:

```
public fun login(io: () -> ResLogin): Unit {}
```

I don’t know how to start, and the official website API has been checked for a long time and I haven’t found a similar answer. I hope the boss will give instructions!

Answer (score 2):

The answer has been found, it can be solved by LambdaTypeName.copy(suspending = true), the specific code is as follows：

```
val lambdaTypeName = LambdaTypeName.get(returnType = responseBean)
                FunSpec.builder(it.methodName).addParameter(ParameterSpec.builder("io",lambdaTypeName.copy(suspending = true)).build())
```